# How do I make a HTTP request (for scraping purposes) to an Angular2 site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, request-promise

I'm trying to use a node server to scrape some information from an agular2 Application. The problem is that the response I get is the index.js file, essentially the "loading..." part of the page.

I'm using the npm request or request-promise package like this:

```
var rp = require("request-promise");

rp('https://someurl.com')
    .then((html) => {
        // Do something with the response
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

But I can't figure out if it is possible to wait for the page to actually load. I've looked at possibly using Angular Universal but I need to get the data after it has all loaded and the site owner is against using Universal.

Is there anyway to make this work?

Comment: Have you heard about HATEOAS-like calls ? Given that the app is Angular2 based, you could reverse-engineer its AJAX calling rule/syntax, and then retrieve data in json format by directly requiring a url containing AJAX arguments. However, this methode is of interest only if the website is a sort of "proxy" towards the data you want. If you want to retrieve data that are conditional to what you do directly on the website, you will have to use dynamic web-scraping technics, as explained by Dmytro Medvid below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to get a fully rendered page. Unfortunately, JS rendered web pages can't be reached without rendering process, but we can go through this process using the "headless" browsers, like PhantomJS.

> “A headless browser is a web browser without a graphical user
>   interface. Headless browsers provide automated control of a web page
>   in an environment similar to popular web browsers”

Here I found a good example, which can suite you to move on: https://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-javascript-rendered-sites/

Also, you could check this article, about SEO for Angularjs powered sites, under the "Spitting out the HTML Pages" you can find useful information: https://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html#sptting-out-the-html-pages

Comment: Thank you for that. I actually had used phantomjs before it had just been a while. I actually ended up using the nightmare package https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare

Comment: Yup, the same thing in my opinion. Should work similar to phantom.js.